# Is there any way or IDE to visualize the angular component template as I do in the design view of android studio?

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio, ide, design-view

I am fighting with an angular project which is really in bad condition. Actually, all angular projects I worked on were in very bad conditions. I cannot understand why the enterprise word want this single page applications. Anyway...  In the meantime that someone will tell us how to write FE application in a maintainable way..

Is there any way or IDE to visualize the angular component html template as I do in the design view of android studio? It would really help me to understand how a page has been designed.

Thansks in advance.

I looked on the internet and in StackOverflow... but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly odd question.

Android has the preview feature because in order to see the page you're working on, it needs to completely build the solution and install/run it (on either emulator or real device, whatever you're using). So they provided an entire renderer feature directly in the IDE for you just for visualisation purposes.

Angular is already a pure UI framework that runs and displays with real-time updates (after every save) with, ideally, a simple, single `ng serve` command out of the box.

... the browser is the visualisation IDE.

No matter how clean your project is or not - though hopefully it's in a working state such that it will build and run - it should just be immediately runnable and therefore viewable.

And some minor defence of Angular: the bad state of your apps/the apps you have inherited aren't really a reflection of the framework, rather the developers thereof.

Angular lends itself to having quite clean organisation and layout - if you put the time and care into it as you should any project.